# How to solve minification issue with AEM 6.5 and ECMA Script 6/ javascript 6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, aem, minify

I am working on an AEM 6.5 instance this is a strange issue.
I have set minification engine to min:gcc as min:yui is deprecated since 2012.

Now min:gcc in author instance compiles only a few JS files as the others are throwing errors. But in publish instance it's rejecting every JS file for minification.

Now the problem is I can go back to "yui" BUT that throws errors as well and there is nothing much FE can do as the JS files are not directly written by them, they write ES6 code and transpile and give us ES5. This ES5 transpiled code is getting rejected by YUI and GCC both.

How can they fix issues in a file that Babel has generated?

How do I get out of this dilema?

Comment: Can you post the errors you see from error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up doing somewhat what Sharath has mentioned in his answer.
However I would like to highlight another issue we faced. So to by-pass Adobe Cloud Security warnings we turned on minification service in AEM and individually added ignore property

```
jsProcessor="[default:none,min:none]"
```

adding min:gcc;compilationLevel=whitespace didn't work for use.

And in the HTML Library OSGi service when we set default js and css processor, setting min:gcc caused default AEM authoring library minification to fail.

**It's best that we either turn off minification in Author OR set js processor to min:yui i.e. the default.**

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already using a transpiler, you can add the minification to the FE pipeline and skip minification on AEM altogether. Minification is a global setting in OSGI. If you choose to have it on for some other JS files that are not part of the same FE ecosystem, change the 'compilationLevel' setting on the clientlibs that contain transpiled code to omit minification.

You can "sort of" turn off minification on an individual clientlib by setting the compilationLevel to whitespace. Since the JS already has whitespace removed by the FE build tool it will come out untouched by the clientlib manager and coexist with the typical clientlib paradigm of AEM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
    categories="[clienlib-with-transpiled-code]"
    jsProcessor="[default:none,min:gcc;compilationLevel=whitespace]"
/>
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for us. +1 as you got kinda close to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 months of fighting a similar issue, this worked for me:

```
min:gcc;languageIn=ECMASCRIPT_2016;languageOut=ECMASCRIPT_2016;compilationLevel=simple;obfuscate=true
```

The problem was the "default:none" was generating conflict, try removing "default:none"